# Understanding the CSS position property

Tags: html, css, css-position

I created the following simple HTML to help me understand the position property and I have a simple question about the way the HTML below displays in the browser (Chrome):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .fixdiv {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100px;
        width: 150px;
        top: 0;
        left: 100px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        }
    .absdiv {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        top: 50px;
        left: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        }
    .reldiv {
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
        width: 150px;
        top: 20px;
        left: 100px;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>text with normal flow is this text here.
        text with normal flow is this text here.</p>
        <p>text with normal flow is this text here.
        text with normal flow is this text here.</p>
        <p>text with normal flow is this text here.
        text with normal flow is this text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fixdiv">
        <p>This is a div with fixed position</p>
    </div>
    <div class="absdiv">
        <p>This is a div with absolute position</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reldiv">
        <p>This is a div with relative position</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is fine but I have a question about why, when viewed in a browser, there is some space inserted before the fixed and absolute boxes but not the relative one? See screenshot.
[image: Screen shot of HTML in Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

That’s the paragraph margin. In the fixed or absolute container, you see the margin inside the box. In the relative container, the margin is part of the calculation of the paragraph’s original position, but it doesn’t move with the element.

You can get rid of the extra space by simply setting `margin: 0` on the paragraphs.